# System time in MATLAB using double(tic)

Tags: matlab, time

I am working on a code where i see they used system time by

```
double(tic)
```

I was wondering is it really working as a system time?

and if it is, In what units? (like in C where it counts nsecs from 1842 or something?)

```
double(tic)
>> 4.65E+10
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of tic, as per the documentation is:

> Value of the internal timer at the execution of the tic command. This
>   value is used as an input argument for a subsequent call to toc. You
>   should not rely on the meaning of this value.

Most likely it is the integer value of the clock counts of the timer hardware chip in the processor/motherboard.

Comment: cant believe, the whole system working by it, (the whole network), now should i change and fix it to rl time...? damn

Comment: @JohnnyF cant say, as this is very problem specific. It may only be used for computing time differences.... no idea

Comment: @JohnnyF You may want to use [`now`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/now.html)

Comment: @JohnnyF consider accepting the asnwer if it helped you